# problemas implementado BottonBar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottombar

Hola estoy intentando implementar un `BottonBar` , ya esta en mi archivo xml se muestra perfectamente en la activida el problema es . Para agregarle las funciones android studio no me reconoce `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Este es el codigo .

```
public class Centimeters extends AppCompatActivity {

    private  BottomNavigationItemView bottomNavigationView;
    TextView text1 , text2 , text3 ;
    EditText editText;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_centimeters);

       BottomNavigationItemView bottomNavigationItemView = (BottomNavigationItemView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationItemView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener (new BottomNavigationItemView())



        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();


        text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex1centimeters);
        text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex2centimeters);
        text3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex1centimeters);



        final DecimalFormat decimales = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); /** la cantidad de digitos decimales que se muestra */




        final EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcentimeters);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                if (!(editText.getText().toString()).isEmpty()){

                    double valor = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());



                    if (valor >= 0 ){

                        double resu1 = valor / 3.48; /**centimeters to feet formula */


                        text1.setText(decimales.format(resu1));


                        double resu2= valor / 2.54 ;/**centimeters to inches formula  */

                        text2.setText(decimales.format(resu2));



                        double resu3 = valor*10;/**centimeter to mm formula*/

                        text3.setText(decimales.format(resu3));






                    }

                    else {

                        text1.setText("");
                        text2.setText("");
                        text3.setText("");
                    }
                }




            }
        });

    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.liantonypozo.calculosmatematicos3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })




    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: donde está el error bottomNavigationItemView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener (new BottomNavigationItemView())
 mírate el código del compañero @Jorgesys que es el correcto

Comment: @Webserveis se que es el correcto , pero mira en el capture que android studio no lo reconoce

Comment: Prueba de retirar el @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N) o la otra es crea un activity nuevo usando la galeria y estableces el navigationbar

Comment: @Webserveis ya lo intente sigue el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

Esto es incorrecto ya que estas definiendo un método `BottomNavigationItemView()` ??? y no un listener `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`:

```
bottomNavigationItemView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener (new BottomNavigationItemView())
```

La forma adecuada esta :

```
    BottomNavigationItemView bottomNavigationItemView = (BottomNavigationItemView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationItemView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                    /**** Ejemplo de como realizar una acción al seleccionar un item mediante su id****/
                   switch (item.getItemId()) {
                      case R.id.navigation_home:
                        //Acción
                      return true;
                  case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                       //Acción
                      return true;
                  case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                      //Acción
                      return true;
                   }
                  /************************/




                return false ;
       }
     });
```

hay que recordar agregar la dependencia de la library de diseño dentro del archivo `build.gradle`, recordando que este nuevo widget esta contenido desde la versión `25.0.0`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0' 
compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’
```

y la vista definirla como:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sigue sin reconocer setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Comment: android studio no reconoce esa línea

Comment: me parece que no has agregado la dependencia : compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’

Comment: tengo la 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0' agregada

Comment: tienes estos imports? import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; agrega los imports que tienes y tu build.gradle. Por cierto veo que te falta definir los elementos dentro del menu

Comment: ya tengo esos imports , ya defini los elementos dentro del menu el problema persiste , busque en android developer no veo referencias a ese problema

Comment: agrega tu build.gradle por favor. debes tener compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0' 
compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’ o mayor

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57977/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-liantony-pozo).

Comment: revise el ejemplo y veo todo igual en mi proyecto

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo deberia ser algo así

```
bottomBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```